# Get all classnames that extend a specific class

Tags: java

In my java project, I need to get a variable from each class that extends another class. My problem here is that I don't know the name of these classes. Let's say my classtree looks like this:

```
Package
 - MyProject
 - BaseClass
 - Class 1 extends BaseClass
 - Class 2 extends BaseClass
 - Class 3 extends BaseClass
 - Class 4
 - Class 5
```

Now each Class that extends BaseClass has a variable `baseVariable`, and I need to get its value in `MyProject`. Is there any way to get a list of classes that extend BaseClass, so I can then access the baseVariable value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections):

```
Set<Class<? extends BaseClass>> subclasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(BaseClass.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [ClassPath](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) from Guava.

```
    ClassPath cp = ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    for (ClassPath.ClassInfo n : cp.getAllClasses()) {
        Class cl = n.load();
        if (BaseClass.isAssignableFrom(cl)) {
        }
    }
```